# EMR Notebook Scala kernel import graphframes library

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, graphframes

Running `spark-shell --packages "graphframes:graphframes:0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11"` in the bash shell works and I can successfully import graphframes 0.7, but when I try to use it in a scala jupyter notebook like this:

```
import scala.sys.process._
"spark-shell --packages \"graphframes:graphframes:0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11\""!
import org.graphframes._
```

gives error message:

```
<console>:53: error: object graphframes is not a member of package org
   import org.graphframes._
```

Which from what I can tell means that it runs the bash command, but then still cannot find the retrieved package.

I am doing this on an EMR Notebook running a spark scala kernel.

Do I have to set some sort of spark library path in the jupyter environment?

Answer (score 0):

That simply shouldn't work. What your code does is a simple attempt to start a new independent Spark shell. Furthermore Spark packages have to loaded when the `SparkContext` is initialized for the first time.

You should either add  (assuming these are correct versions)

```
spark.jars.packages graphframes:graphframes:0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11
```

to your Spark configuration files, or use equivalent in your `SparkConf` / `SparkSessionBuilder.config`  before `SparkSession` is initialized.

Comment: ahh, so what I appear to be doing is making a second spark-shell that includes my library, but then not using it since I am already using an instance of spark-shell. Is this correct?